# how to reindex and clear data from cluster in elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, kibana

I'm getting an error in my elastic search logs like

> [yCpzt6z] path: /.kibana_task_manager/_doc/_search, params:
> {ignore_unavailable=true, index=.kibana_task_manager, type=_doc}
> org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all
> shards failed    at
> org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:296)
> [elasticsearch-6.8.9.jar:6.8.9]
> at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:133)
> [elasticsearch-6.8.9.jar:6.8.9]

I'm using docker-compose for ELK configuration, after every 2-3
minutes my containers are restarting automatically and elastic cluster status
are in red.

epoch timestamp cluster status

```
node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks
max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent 1605689035 08:43:55 
docker-cluster red             1         1     17  17    0    4    
 1974             1                  -                  0.9%
```

Comment: Can you show the full error log you're getting?

Comment: The log message is indicating that a search has failed to search any of the shards it tried. The shards themselves are still starting up at this point, which can take some time.

Comment: On the other hand, you may have far too many shards given the size of your cluster. so you can try to change your sharding strategy

Comment: I'm asking for the full logs because there was a bug with async search that's been resolved

Comment: @val can we resolve this issue by clear the cluster but ,i don't want to loose my data  and  how can i share my hole log file here .

Comment: I'm not asking for the whole log, just the few lines of the error, but the full error

Comment: [2020-11-19T10:55:52,465][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [yCpzt6z] path: /.kibana_task_manager/_doc/_search, params: {ignore_unavailable=true, index=.kibana_task_manager,type=_doc}org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failedorg.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:296) [elasticsearch-6.8.9.jar:6.8.9]org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:133) [elasticsearch-6.8.9.jar:6.8.9]